# Change font size caption or title in xtable in markdown

Tags: r, markdown, xtable, longtable

I want to change the font size for my title/caption in the table made using `xtable`. The following code changes the size of the text in the table, but not the caption/title.

```
Tab <- xtable::xtable(myTable, caption="\\tt Title")
print(Tab, floating=TRUE, size="\\fontsize{6pt}{8pt}\\selectfont")
```

However, if using `longtable` (for which you need `\usepackage{longtable}`) as shown below, the caption has the correct font size.

```
Tab <- xtable::xtable(myTable, caption="\\tt Title")
print(Tab, floating=TRUE, tabular.environment="longtable", size="\\fontsize{6pt}{8pt}\\selectfont")
```